# "System program problem detected" after login?

Tags: 16.04, graphics, login, hp, hp-pavilion

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP Pavilion dm4 laptop the other day and everything was working fine until yesterday. I started up my laptop, but for some reason, at the login screen, I didn't see my wallpaper so I immediately knew something was wrong. When I login, it flashes the "System program problem detected" in the top right corner while the rest of the screen is black. I believe this is the same problem described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) thread, but no solution is working for my laptop.

Hopefully someone will reply to me soon, I have homework I need to complete...

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 9):

Can you open the terminal? (ctrl - alt - t) If so, try:

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176406
I think this was the same problem.

Comment: I can't do the Ctrl - Alt - t thing, but I can do Ctrl - Alt - F1.

Answer (score 0):

**Recover with help of Ubuntu Updates**

Hi, try following steps. (**Note:Connect to internet before you can do anything**)

- After login, press **CTRL+ALT+F1**
- Now, you need to provide username and password for accessing the terminal
- Run this command first:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Then run this command after it:

  ```
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```
- Wait everything to done. Then restart your system with this command:

  ```
  shutdown -r 0
  ```

After restarting, your computer or Ubuntu system should be recovered. Remember that, the system packages will be updates as we run **update** and **upgrade** commands.

Answer (score 0):

Error still occuring, although no errors occured during update or upgrade.. However, I did notice there were two differing packages offered while using update.  I am attempting to isolate the reason why, because as far as I know.. this is supposed to be a stable release of Ubuntu.

Comment: please do your own question, provided any elements and steps that you try and each results that fails